# onCreateOptionsMenu doesn't set icons or options in the ActionBar the first time the activity is loaded in Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm using the normal onCreateOptionsMenu with a MenuInflater to load my menu from xml for the action bar and it works fine on Honeycomb but for some reason on Ice Cream Sandwich it doesn't load the first time, subsequent trips to the activity will yield the expected items on the action bar.

Here's my onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
    Log.e("test", "createmenu");
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.map_menu, menu);
    //      if (presets.size() == 0)
    //          menu.getItem(4).setEnabled(false);
    return true;
}
```

And here's my menu xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/info"
    android:icon="@drawable/info"
    android:title="Info"
    android:showAsAction="always" />
<item android:id="@+id/preset"
    android:title="Display Preset Option"
    android:icon="@drawable/presets"
    android:showAsAction="always"  />
    <item android:id="@+id/favorites"
    android:title="Favorites"        
    android:icon="@drawable/favorites"
    android:showAsAction="always"  />
<item android:id="@+id/add_favorite"
    android:title="Add Favorite"         
    android:icon="@drawable/plus"
    android:showAsAction="always" />
<item android:id="@+id/location"
    android:title="Current Location"
    android:icon="@drawable/location"
    android:showAsAction="always" />
<item android:id="@+id/return_map"
    android:title="Return to Original Map"              
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />
<item android:id="@+id/raster"
    android:title="Show Raster" 
    android:icon="@drawable/raster"
    android:showAsAction="always" />
<item android:id="@+id/query"
    android:title="Queries"
    android:icon="@drawable/queries"
    android:showAsAction="always" />
<item android:id="@+id/displayNotes"
    android:title="Hide Notes" />
<item android:id="@+id/displayPhotos"
    android:title="Display Photos"
    android:visible="false" />
<item android:id="@+id/add_note"
    android:title="Add Note"/>
<item android:id="@+id/help"
    android:title="Help"/>
<item android:id="@+id/email"
    android:title="Email Map"/>
</menu>
```

Anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: Try `return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));` instead of `return true`.

Comment: @CommonsWare no dice, I'm still seeing the same behavior.

Comment: Here's a sample project that works fine for me: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Menus/ActionBarBC

Comment: Strangely enough that project works fine for me also.

Comment: I also have another activity that I use the same onCreateOptionsMenu code for and it works fine. I'm not sure why it works for one activity but not the other.

Comment: All I can suggest is that you slowly change the one that works to look like the one that doesn't, until you stumble upon your issue.

Comment: The only difference is the xml file I load and I tried to load it in place of the map_menu.xml file and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a case where onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu) was returning false instead of super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu) and fixing that has solved my problem. I guess something has changed as of Ice Cream Sandwich. Either way, if you're experiencing the same problem as I had make sure you're returning super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu) and not false.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to do it:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menuColores: /your code here


<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+id/menuColores" android:alphabeticShortcut="k"
android:icon="@drawable/palette" /> </menu>
```

I'm developing an app and this is a snippet of my code.. it works just fine! sometimes I have to clean the project when I change the item's image, it may not recognize the image otherwise

Comment: My problem is that the action bar items aren't showing up the first time I load the activity, not that I can't select them.